# Java Case Converter, most of the program is done, having trouble with case options?

Tags: java, type-conversion, case, uppercase, lowercase

My program worked fine before I tried implementing the conversion options. All I am trying to do is implement a U/u or L/l input option for either convert the string to Uppercase or Lowercase. Help please?

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

   public class CaseManipulation {


   public static void main(String[] args) {

       boolean up, low;
       char up[] = {'U', 'u'};
       char low[] = {'L', 'l'};

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter an input String: ");
       String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Case Conversion Option(U/u for uppercase, L/l for lowercase):");
       char caseoption = scanner.nextLine();

       if (caseoption == up[]) {
           System.out.println("Upper Case: " + toUpperCase(inputString));
       }  else if (caseoption == low[]) {
           System.out.println("Lower Case: " + toLowerCase(inputString));
       }

       //is_uppercase();


       //System.out.println("Upper Case: " + toUpperCase(inputString));
       //System.out.println("Lower Case: " + toLowerCase(inputString));

       }

       //public static boolean is_uppercase(char caseoption) {
      // if (char caseoption == ) {

         //  } 

   //}

       public static String toUpperCase(String inputString) {
       String result = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
           char currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);
           char currentCharToUpperCase = Character.toUpperCase(currentChar);
           result = result + currentCharToUpperCase;
       }
       return result;
   }

   public static String toLowerCase(String inputString) {
       String result = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
           char currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);
           char currentCharToLowerCase = Character.toLowerCase(currentChar);
           result = result + currentCharToLowerCase;
       }
       return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your `if` condition is comparing the object/memory references of the two objects, not their values...

```
if (caseoption == up[]) {...
```

`caseoption` is never likely to be equal to `up`...

Instead, you should be comparing their contents...

```
if (caseoption == up[0] || caseoption == up[1]) {...
```

A simpler solution might be to convert the `caseoption` into a single use case, for example...

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(caseoption) == 'U') {...
```